# Django: updating a field with a progressive number within an ordered queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Using Django 1.2.3, I need to update a model field with a ranking among an ordered set of instances, without having to retrieve the entire queryset and update each model by hand.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Comment: The docs explain how to update a field with either a constant value or a value from another field in the same record. In my case, the value should be a variable, increased at any iteration

Comment: Alittle more information could help, could you please provide more details on what you are trying to do?